# MySQL Connection Problem

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I create web site and I use MYSQL database by MySQL Connection 5.1;

Sometimes my web site freezing; usually in the login page; I cilck the login button and I wait 10 minutes but I can not login.

After I restart the IIS,  Everthing works fine. After 30 or 40 times loging the page , again page freezing. I wait again. After I restart the ISS. It's go on like this.

So What is the my mistake?

I use DataSet for mysql tables. I use mysql-connector-net-5.2.6 connection.

Comment: Post some code and config files please.

Comment: have you done all setting for virtual directory? check setting of your application in IIS and also check authentication mode setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freezing may be caused by connections that are left open - are you disposing the datasets after use? Does MySQL Administrator show many open connections?

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont you create the application without the use of Dataset Datatype(for testing purpose) and check whether the freezing happens?
I assume there will be complexity involved in implementing the Dataset Type.

Check for the Server Configuration as well, Make sure that Memory is not been used by other busy application like Video editing software... etc